# Angular 2 final release: Cannot find name 'PatternDetails'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm getting an error that 'PatternList' (which is an interface created by me) is not found. If I try to import it I get an error that PatternDetails is not a module. I'm not sure what causes this error. I faced this error while I'm trying to configure Webpack in my angular2 project.

Here is one of my components that uses PatternDetails interface:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pattern-detail',
  template: `
    <div class="pattern-detail" [ngClass]='{active: metadata.status.backendValidationStatus == "FAIL",
      unactive: metadata.status.backendValidationStatus == "OK",
      warning: metadata.status.backendValidationStatus == "WARN",
      selected: metadata.selected
    }' (click)="patternClicked(metadata)">
      <div class="name-details">
        <h3>{{metadata.displayName}}</h3>
        <p>{{metadata.details}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="time-details">
        <p class='last_update'>{{metadata.lastupdate}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['/css/pattern_detail.css']
})
export class PatternDetailComponent {

  @Input() metadata:PatternDetails;
  @Output() selectPattern = new EventEmitter<PatternDetails>();

  patternClicked(pattern: PatternDetails) {
    this.selectPattern.emit(pattern);
  }

}
```

Here is the PatternDetails interface:

```
interface PatternDetails {
  patternClass: string;
  version: string;
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
  lastupdate: string;
  details: string;
  status: Status;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

I'm not sure what else I should include, but after my investigation I found that there might be an issue with tsconfig.json, so I include it as well:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "types" : [
    "core-js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, PatternListComponent, PatternDetailComponent, WidgetListComponent,
    FormComponent, DefaultWidget, LabelComponent, CheckboxWidget ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ WidgetService ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Post your `AppModule`.

Comment: done :)  I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your interface:

```
export interface PatternDetails {

...

}
```

Comment: @ZolcsakTamas Check my edited answer, you didn't export your interface, therefore, you can't import it.

Comment: Adding export to the interface works :) But I didn't need to add PatternDetails to AppModule, it works just by adding export to the interface. Thank you :D

Comment: @ZolcsakTamas Great, I edited my answer to avoid confusion if someone encounters the same problem. Glad I could help.